# Add Product Permalink in woocommerce admin order page

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to add the permalink of product on woocommerce admin order page with this code:

```
function fpd_custom_order_item_values($_product) {

$url = $_product->permalink;

echo '<p>'.$url.'</p>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta', 'fpd_custom_order_item_values', 100, 1);
```

However, this does not output the product permalink. When I replace `$url = $_product->permalink;` with `$url = $_product->name;`, the name gets echoed. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `permalink` property of a product. Permalinks are not stored in the database, because they're generated based on a number of external factors. Therefore you need to use a function to retrieve the permalink. In WooCommerce the best way to do this is with:

```
function fpd_custom_order_item_values($_product) {
    $url = $_product->get_permalink();

    echo '<p>' . esc_url( $url ) . '</p>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta', 'fpd_custom_order_item_values', 100, 1);
```

Also, make sure you're escaping your output. Since this is a URL, use `esc_url()`.

Comment: This is working fine for orders with products but if an order contains products + flat rate shipping (which does not have a permalink), there's an error as shipping charge doesn't have any permalink. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
function fpd_custom_order_item_values($item_id, $item, $product) {
    $url = get_permalink($product->get_id());
    echo '<p>'.$url.'</p>';}

add_action('woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'fpd_custom_order_item_values', 10, 3);
```

The function name is changed to fpd_custom_order_item_values to match the function you specified in your question.

The function now takes three arguments: $item_id, $item, and $product. These variables are used to get the product ID and retrieve the permalink for the product.

The $url variable is set using the get_permalink() function, which takes the product ID as an argument.

The add_action() hook is changed to woocommerce_order_item_meta_end to ensure that the permalink is displayed at the end of the order item meta data.

By making these modifications, you should be able to display the product permalink on the WooCommerce admin order page.